# Sharing Microsoft Stream videos to external users

Tags: video-streaming, users, sharing, microsoft, external

Is there a way to share microsoft stream videos to external users? (that don't have a Microsoft account).

Downloading and uploading to share point isn't really an option as I'm getting the 'failied - network error'.